# How to make all faces the same dimensions?

Tags: modeling

I notice a when I model, a lot of times the faces will be different lengths and widths even with extrusion.  Or even if you made a mistake and need to clean up a mesh, is there a way to select faces and make them all even in size compared to the surrounding faces?  [image]

Another example would be making the crooked faces on the right of this picture the same as the even ones on the left:

[image]

**EDIT:** This is what happens when I scale to 0:

[image]

[image]

Comment: select the top row of vertices on the right side, and press S+Z+0 to bring them to the same height (on the Z axis), then do the same with the bottom row.

Comment: Oh right yes that works for the second example, but for the first how would I do that?  Because in the first example if I do that all the faces go completely flat on the x axis (i.e. if I were to select all the pink parts the would just go flat instead of staying where they are, but becoming uniform in size).

Comment: scale to 0 on the axis you need.

Comment: I tried that and it messed up the faces.  I posted screenshots.

Comment: You have to select different sections separately, otherwise all of the verities will end up being scaled in the same place

Comment: So there's nothing that sort of averages out the dimensions of a number faces selected and makes them more or less the same size?  I tried space in loop tools but that didn't work.